# Getting a real time position feedback from rviz?

Tags: ros, navigation, publisher, amcl, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We all know that if we want to get the position of your robot we are using the amcl, now my goal is to get a real time x,y position of the robot as shown in rviz interface itself and display it in a loop in the Linux terminal, how do I do it. I have create a listener.cpp file, do I change amcl file to work like a talker since whatever the talker publish, the listener will receive? Or do I implant the cl codes into my listener.cpp? I'm a bit confused.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11215/getting-a-real-time-position-feedback-from-rviz?/) by [cheyanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/1055/cheyanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to edit the amcl node at all. In the documentation [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl) you can see that the amcl node publishes to a topic called amcl_pose that represents the robot's position with respect to the map origin. All you have to do is open a new terminal and type the following:

```
rostopic echo /amcl_pose
```

You can find a tutorial on using rostopic [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rostopic).

Another option if you're going to be porting the information to a GUI application, you could run amcl while using [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag), and then view it afterwards with [rxbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxbag) to view it, export it to .csv files, etc.

**EDIT:** In order to then return data to the robotino_base node, first look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robotino_base) to see what topics that the node subscribes to. If you want to publish to cmd_vel, you can see that the type is geometry_msgs/Twist (all cmd_vel messages are of this type). So to do this, you must use:

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[1.0,0.0,0.0]' '[0.0,0.0,0.0]'
```

For more information on how to specify the contents of the message, you can look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine). I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3